# Find the underlying Docker file you are importing from

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file that imports from a php tag:

`FROM php:5.6.32-apache`

Is there a way to see the underlying Dockerfile of the 5.6.32-apache, given that it is not present in https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master

Comment: there are links to Dockerfile of all the versions: https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: @matanper not to all. Check out the older tags on this page: https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=69 . Obviously links are present only for the latest tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general sense, the answer is "no". The Dockerfile you want may not exist at all. (There are more ways to make an image than using Dockerfile, after all.)

You can get quite a lot of information about an image using docker inspect, including `"Created": "2018-01-04T04:08:09.885971603Z"` for php:5.6.32-apache. Using that information I was able to dig back in the repository history to find old commits containing 5.6. Considering further, `git log --grep 5.6.32` might do the trick, too, and is easier to try:

There are only [two commits](https://github.com/docker-library/php/search?q=5.6.32&type=Commits) with 5.6.32 in the commit message. This is a good place to begin your search. [More generally for 5.6](https://github.com/docker-library/php/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=5.6&type=Commits), you can see that 5.6.40 was the last one, and it was removed some time ago.

Comment: `docker history` can also be useful to see the layers that build the image (except the original `FROM`)

Comment: @kojiro thanks. Reviewing the search of commits using the link in your answer I was able to find a version of the Dockerfile I was looking for from the github repo: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ec6b6e60b42c283d48775596f722f5250c1f5ca5/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile